# overload of operator: ok MSVS but fails in g++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have code which compiles without error in Visual Studio 2010. 
But g++ puts error

```
CComplex.cpp: In member function 'Complex Complex::operator+(Complex&)':
CComplex.cpp:22: error: no matching function for call to 'Complex::Complex(Complex)'
CComplex.cpp:15: note: candidates are: Complex::Complex(Complex&)
make: *** [CComplex.o] Error 1
```

Please tell me what's the problem with my code.

Complex.h

```
class Complex
{
public:
  Complex();
  Complex(double _Re, double _Im);
  Complex(Complex& c);
  Complex operator+(Complex& num);
  inline double& fRe(void){return Re;}
  inline double& fIm(void){return Im;}
protected:
  double Re;
  double Im;
}
```

Complex.cpp

```
Complex::Complex(){
    Re = 0.0;
    Im = 0.0;
}
Complex::Complex(double re, double im){
    Re = re;
    Im = im;
}
Complex::Complex(Complex& complex){
    *this = complex;
}
Complex Complex::operator+(Complex& num){
    return Complex(Re + num.fRe(), Im + num.fIm());
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Complex Complex::operator+(Complex& num){
    return Complex(Re + num.fRe(), Im + num.fIm());
};
```

In return calls copy c-tor for temporary-object, that cannot be binded to lvalue-reference. Use

```
Complex(const Complex& c);
```

And for `operator +` use also

`Complex operator + (const Complex& c)`

or

`Complex operator + (Complex c)`

For first case functions `fRe` and `fIm` shall be constant functions, or you should do explicit copy of passed object.

It can be compiled in MSVC and not compiled in g++, because [MSVC wrongly does not check for an existence of acceptable copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6524855/16673) when performing [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).