# C++ constructor prevents successful compile

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, initializer-list

I am facing s strange issue in C++ and I'd appreciate an explanation. This snippet fails to compile:

```
size_t bufLength = 18;
char* buffer = new char[bufLength];
auto_array_ptr<char> pBuffer1 = buffer;  // fails
auto_array_ptr<char> pBuffer2(buffer);
```

The 3rd line above fails with `No viable constructor copying variable of type 'auto_array_ptr<char>'`. Note that the next line compiles just fine.

Q1) This in itself is strange to me. I thought initialisation with an assignment was transformed into initialisation with an initialiser when necessary. Why could the first fail if the second succeeds?

Q2) But the real puzzle for me is that the failing line succeeds when I *remove* a constructor from the `auto_array_ptr` class: the `auto_array_ptr(auto_array_ptr)` constructor. I really have a hard time understanding what's happening here.

I can sort of imagine a scenario here of what the compiler might be trying to do here:

1- look for a void `operator=(char *p)`. Not found. Let's see if we can promote the argument (`buffer`).
2- ah ah, there is an `operator=(auto_array_ptr&)`. So I win if I can promote `buffer` to an `auto_array_ptr`. Let's look for a constructor to do that.
3- ah ah there is a `auto_array_ptr(auto_array_ptr&)` constructor. So let's construct a temporary variable from `buffer` using that constructor (`temp`).
4- now try to use the `operator=(auto_array_ptr&)`, method. But bummer: its argument is not `const`, and I can't actually use it. Report an error.

But this scenario is not convincing. For one, the compiler could notice the `const` problem is step 2. Also, it could use the `auto_array_ptr(char *)` directly rather than trying to promote  `buffer`. Then, if I add a `operator=(char *p)` to the class, the error doesn't go away. Finally, that doesn't explain why *removing* the `auto_array_ptr(auto_array_ptr&)` helps.

Of course you need the source of `auto_array_ptr`. here it is:

```
template<class T>
class auto_array_ptr
{
public:
    auto_array_ptr(T *p = 0) : ptr(p) {}
    auto_array_ptr(auto_array_ptr<T>& a) : ptr(a.release()) {}  // remove this line to compile
    ~auto_array_ptr() {if(ptr != 0) {delete[] ptr; ptr = 0;}}

    void operator=(auto_array_ptr<T>& a) {if(&a != this) reset(a.release());}
//    void operator=(T *p) { if(p != ptr) reset(p);}    // adding this doesn't help

    T& operator[](int i) const {return ptr[i];}
    T& operator[](unsigned int i) const {return ptr[i];}
    operator T*() const {return ptr;}
    T* get() const {return ptr;}

    T* release() {T* tmp = ptr; ptr = 0; return tmp;}

    void reset(T *p = 0) {if(ptr != 0) {delete[] ptr;}; ptr = p;}

private:
    T *ptr;
};
```

The compiler is a recent version of Clang running in Xcode 4.4 under Mac OS X Lion. I believe it's based on LLVM 3.1. A slightly more recent version in Xcode 4.5 behaves exactly the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Also, related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222076/why-is-copy-constructor-called-instead-of-conversion-constructor

Answer (score 4):

```
auto_array_ptr<char> pBuffer1 = buffer;  // fails
```

create `temporary auto_array_ptr<char>` from `buffer` and copy it to `pBuffer1`.

```
auto_array_ptr(auto_array_ptr<T>& a)
```

your `copy c-tor` receive `reference`. You cannot bind `temporary` to `reference`, so, compilation fails.

> Q2) But the real puzzle for me is that the failing line succeeds when
>   I remove a constructor from the auto_array_ptr class: the
>   auto_array_ptr(auto_array_ptr) constructor. I really have a hard time
>   understanding what's happening here.

Compiler will create `copy c-tor` with `signature`

```
auto_array_ptr(const auto_array_ptr&)
```

Comment: In other words, the OP's fallacy is that he does not separate clone construction (i.e., copy construction from same type) from implicit casting to that type. If the OP has access to the `auto_array_ptr` declaration, he should add a copy constructor with move semantics.

Comment: I do have access to `auto_array_ptr`, with restrictions (I need to justify any modification to it). It so happens that the failing line compiles just fine under VC++. So I need to be able to explain the need for a change. Here what would be the signature of a 'copy constructor with move semantics' (if not an implementation)? Also note that I can't use C++11 unfortunately.

Comment: @Jean-DenisMuys Compiler cannot create copy c-tor, if there is explicit declaration copy c-tor (user defined). VC can compile, since if copy will be elided, MSVC doesn't check, that copy c-tor is suitable. It's bug in MSVC. For more information about this bug see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001054/overload-of-operator-ok-msvs-but-fails-in-g/12001125#12001125

Answer (score 3):

This is copy initialization:

```
auto_array_ptr<char> pBuffer1 = buffer;  // fails
```

This creates a temporary `auto_array_ptr<char>` from `buffer` and then uses the **copy constructor** for `pBuffer1`. (subject to optimizations) This fails because the copy constructor is declared as:

```
auto_array_ptr(auto_array_ptr<T>& a)
```

and a temporary cannot bind to a non-`const` reference. Change it to

```
auto_array_ptr(const auto_array_ptr<T>& a)
```

This is direct initialization:

```
auto_array_ptr<char> pBuffer2(buffer);
```

only uses the conversion constructor.

Comment: The OP is actually in a bind, because changing the copy constructor to `const&` would mean that you call `release` (which releases ownership and thus change state) on a `const` object.

Comment: I get that. Does this mean that there is no legal way to use copy-initialization for a such a smart pointer class?