# C++ constructor implicit conversion not happening

Tags: c++, constructor, implicit-conversion

I defined a class A

```
class A{
public:
  A(int){}
private:
  A(const A&);
  A& operator=(const A&);
};
```

I thought that since I give a constructor from int, 
the implicit construction is granted... 
Anyway while

```
A myA(7);
```

works fine, g++ gives me on this line:

```
A myA = 7;
```

the following error:

```
Test02.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
Test02.cpp:5:3: error: ‘A::A(const A&)’ is private
Test02.cpp:12:12: error: within this context
```

Another compiler instead is happy with this conversion. 
Where's the truth? How should I define A so that I get A myA = 7; working?

Comment: `A myA(7)` uses the public `A(int)`, whereas the other line needs both that constructor and the private copy ctor. Do you mean it to be private?

Comment: VC6 is happy, g++ 4.7.3 is unhappy

Comment: @jimifiki VC6 is too old to be reliable for anything - it's older than the (first!) C++ standard.

Comment: vc2010 did have similar problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524185/private-copy-constructor-assignment-operator-and-copy-initialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC is right. `A myA(7);` is *direct initialisation* - it initialises `myA` using the constructor taking an `int` parameter.

`A myA = 7;` is *copy initialisation* - it initialises a temporary `A` object using the `int` constructor, and then initialises `myA` from this temporary using a copy constructor. Even though the copy will most likely be elided in practice, it must still be legal. And sinec the copy constructor is not accessible, it fails.

To make `A myA = 7;` work, you'll have to make the copy (or move) constructor accessible - which basically means making it public.

Comment: public and not defined... finger crossing... It compiles! Wow!

Comment: is it portable what I did? I mean declaring the copy construction giving no implementation. Is it possible that another (standard compliant) compiler doesn't copy initialize because it cannot link the copy construction? As far as I understand §12.8/15, "an implementation is allowed to omit the copy construction" means it can also require copy construction.

Comment: @jimifiki I'd say that it's not 100% portable. If the compiler decides not to perform copy elision (which is always optional), it will require the copy ctor code.

Answer (score 3):

g++ is right about this. The issue is that

```
A myA = 7;
```

is a *copy initialization* That means that, semantically, you have an implicit conversion to `A` on the RHS, and then a copy construction. The actual copy may be elided, but the copy constructor must still be accessible.

On the other hand,

```
A myA(7);
```

is a *direct initialization*. This only requires the converting constructor `A(int)`.

More on *direct initialization* vs. *copy initialization* [here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm).